# .htaccess hide filename at the end of the url

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following code to rewrite a url on my website:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about/organisation$ pages/about/organisation [NC,L]
```

This hides the "pages" bit of the url, But if the user types in "about/organisation/index.php" they still get to the page and index.php is shown. What I want to do is if they type in the index.php it redirects them to "about/organisation" effectively hiding the file name.

I have tried this but it didnt work.

```
RewriteRule ^about/organisation$ pages/about/organisation/index.php [NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: from the answers it seems that my server doesnt let me access the relevant files so Ill have to solve that one first

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try your rule like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /about/organisation/([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^ /about/organisation? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
REwriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^about/organisation/?$ pages/about/organisation [NC,L]
```

Comment: I tried this but the page just isnt displayed. it just says page cannot be found.

Comment: Wait are you trying to redirect index.php to the folder or are you trying to include it so if they type in index.php it will redirect regardless?

Comment: I want it so if the user types the folder name, it stays the folder name, if the user adds any filename after it then it redirects to the folder

Comment: same problem. how do i check if the module is installed. because it seems wiered

Comment: You mean Rewrite? It should be on, because you would get a 500 error if it wasn't. do you have AllowOverride All set for .htaccess

Comment: how can I find out if its on?

Comment: Well put some random text at the top of your htacess file. If you don't get a 500 internal error then its not on.

Comment: Thats weird. If you have access to config file Check your virtualhost and see if AllowOverride is set to All

Comment: oh ive looked into it i dont have access to mod_auth and AuthUserFile so I think its my server.

Comment: That should have anything to do with .htaccess. in your Virtual host file where you set the domain name, document root etc. is where you typically have AllowOverride directive if it's not there it should be added. it's none by default

Comment: I am using a synology rack so I dont have access to those files, its set up in the top level GUI and that means i dont have control of those options

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(about/organisation/).+$ $1 [R=302,L,NE,NC]

RewriteRule ^about/organisation/?$ pages/about/organisation [NC,L]
```

Comment: again as the previous answer it just says the page cant be displayed. but it does change the url

Comment: Well earlier rule is your existing rule which isn't working. What happens when you enter `example.com/about/organisation/` ?

Comment: i just get this: Sorry, the page you are looking for is not found.

Comment: Well then your earlier rule isn't already working. Is `example.com/pages/about/organisation/` working? I suspect not.

Comment: It that rule worked then `example.com/pages/about/organisation/` will not be 404. I am going offline now. Will check back this thread in my morning.